# Using localization in .NET MAUI picker

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

`I created resx files in my .NET MAUI project to use different languages. I want to use them within a picker. I followed the approach below in XAML, but it didn't work. What should I do?

```
<Picker Title="{x:Static resx:AppResources.PickerTitle}">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>{x:Static resx:AppResources.Option1}</x:String>
            <x:String>{x:Static resx:AppResources.Option2}</x:String>
            <x:String>{x:Static resx:AppResources.Option3}</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is a possible solution that uses *Behaviours* and *WeakReferenceMessenger*. Not all that pretty but has possibilities.

Requirement is that you have made the resources for the different language you want.

Let us start with the implementation. We got a picker and a radio buttons group. The picker got a Behavior that is going to do all the magic.

```xml
<Picker x:Name="MyPicker" Title="{x:Static localization:AppResources.PickerTitle}">
   <Picker.Behaviors>
      <local:LocalizedPickerBehavior />
   </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
<local:RadioButtonGroup />
```

We create the behaviour. Here we initialize the Messenger that will tell the Behaviour that we have changed language.

```cs
public class LocalizedPickerBehavior : Behavior<Picker>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Picker picker)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(picker);

        // Set the ItemsSource of the Picker
        SetItemsSource(picker);


        // Listen for the LanguageChanged notification
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<LocalizedPickerBehaviorMessage>(this, (recipient, message) => {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(message.Value);
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            SetItemsSource(picker);
        });
    }

    private void SetItemsSource(Picker picker)
    {
        var option1 = AppResources.Option1;
        var option2 = AppResources.Option2;
        var option3 = AppResources.Option3;

        picker.Title = AppResources.PickerTitle;
        var currentIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        picker.ItemsSource = new List<string> { option1, option2, option3 };
        picker.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Picker picker)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(picker);

        picker.ItemsSource = null;

        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<LocalizedPickerBehavior>(this);
    }
}
```

For the messenger we need a message that we send with the language we want to change to.

```cs
public class LocalizedPickerBehaviorMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public LocalizedPickerBehaviorMessage(string lang) : base(lang)
    {
    }
}
```

And we finnish of with a simple radio button that sends the message to our behaviour.

```cs
public class RadioButtonGroup : StackLayout
{
    public RadioButton RadioButton1 { get; private set; }
    public RadioButton RadioButton2 { get; private set; }

    public RadioButtonGroup()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        RadioButton1 = new RadioButton { Content = "English" };
        RadioButton2 = new RadioButton { Content = "Swedish" };

        RadioButton1.CheckedChanged += OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged;
        RadioButton2.CheckedChanged += OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged;

        Children.Add(RadioButton1);
        Children.Add(RadioButton2);

        RadioButton1.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;

        if (radioButton == RadioButton1 && RadioButton1.IsChecked)
        {
            RadioButton2.IsChecked = false;
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new LocalizedPickerBehaviorMessage("en"));
        }
        else if (radioButton == RadioButton2 && RadioButton2.IsChecked)
        {
            RadioButton1.IsChecked = false;
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new LocalizedPickerBehaviorMessage("sv"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it with two languages (English, German) where English is the default language:

```
<StackLayout Padding="20">
    <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Title}" FontSize="24" />
    <Picker x:Name="languagePicker" Title="Select Language" SelectedIndexChanged="OnLanguagePickerIndexChanged">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>English</x:String>
                <x:String>German</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace YourAppName
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnLanguagePickerIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedLanguage = languagePicker.SelectedItem as string;

            if (selectedLanguage == "English")
            {
                SetLanguage("en");
            }
            else if (selectedLanguage == "German")
            {
                SetLanguage("de");
            }
        }

        private void SetLanguage(string languageCode)
        {
            CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(languageCode);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;

            // Refresh the current page to update the localized strings
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Create resource files for each language. For example:

- AppResources.resx (Default - English)
- AppResources.de.resx (German)

Open each resource file and add localized strings with the same names but different values for each language. For example, for the "Title" key:

AppResources.resx (Default - English):

```
Key: Title, Value: My App
```

AppResources.de.resx (German):

```
Key: Title, Value: Meine App
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain what I want to do correctly. Actually, I have two radio buttons. When I press these buttons, they provide language translations in the corresponding fields. However, I couldn't achieve the same functionality within a picker. In other words, when I press these radio buttons, I want the language of the values inside the picker to change according to the selected radio button.