# Change Text of SearchBar Cancel-Button

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I provide the possibility to change the language internally.

Right now, I don't know how I could change the language of the Cancel-Button of a SearchBar.

I tried with my own SearchBarHandler

```cs
public class SearchBarHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler
{
    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiSearchBar platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        ...
    }
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```cs
...
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            ...
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                //The handler will only be called if the target platform is iOS
#if IOS
                handlers.AddHandler<SearchBar, SearchBarHandler>();
#endif
            });
...
```

... as well as my own Mapper

```cs
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CancelButton", (handler, view) =>
{     
    if (view is Button btn)
    {
        btn.Text = "Hello World";
    }
});
```

So far, I don't know how I could get to the SearchBar-Cancel-Button with one of these methods and also don't know if it would work then.

The reason is that when I switch the App language internally it should also re-apply on the SearchBar-Cancle-Button when displayed next time.

How could I solve this and how do I get to the Cancel-Button to change its Text and also would this change the Text on Android and iOS?

==== Update =====

**SearchBarHandler-Implementation**

```cs
public class SearchBarHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler
{
    public LanguageResourceManager LanguageResourceManager { get; }

    public SearchBarHandler()
    {
        LanguageResourceManager = LanguageResourceManager.Instance;
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<LocalizationChangedMessage>(this, HandleLocalizationChangedMessage);
    }

    private void HandleLocalizationChangedMessage(object recipient, LocalizationChangedMessage message)
    {
        UpdateCancelButtonText(base.PlatformView);
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiSearchBar platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        UpdateCancelButtonText(platformView);
    }

    private void UpdateCancelButtonText(MauiSearchBar platformView)
    {
        var cancelButtonText = Translate("CancelButtonText");
        platformView.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(cancelButtonText), new NSString("cancelButtonText"));
    }

    private string Translate(string resourceString, object parameter = null)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return $"{LanguageResourceManager[resourceString]}";
        }

        return string.Format(LanguageResourceManager[resourceString].ToString(), parameter);
    }
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```cs
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            ...
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                //The handler will only be called if the target platform is iOS
#if IOS
                handlers.AddHandler<SearchBar, SearchBarHandler>();
#endif
            });
```

Comment: For Android, [Cancel-Button is a `ImageView`](https://imgur.com/a/3au6Bbv). It couldn't Modify `Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Android has a text on the Cancel button, just an X. But for IOS you use the native `SetValueForKey`

```cs
PlatformView.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject("Clear"), new NSString("cancelButtonText"));
```

[image]

**Update**

To make this work you need to make a control and derive it from SearchBar, as well as from the handler. You can still use Weak Reference but not for the handler, just if you want to update it from outside the view.

```cs
public partial class SearchBarLang : SearchBar
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CancelButtonTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CancelButtonText), typeof(string), typeof(SearchBarLang), defaultValue: AppResources.CancelButtonText);

    public string CancelButtonText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CancelButtonTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(CancelButtonTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The `SearchBarHandler` will look like this

```cs
public partial class SearchBarExHandler 
{
    public static readonly IPropertyMapper<ISearchBar, SearchBarHandler> SearchBarMapper =
        new PropertyMapper<ISearchBar, SearchBarHandler>(Mapper)
        {
            ["CancelButtonText"] = MapCancelText,
        };

    public SearchBarExHandler() : base(SearchBarMapper)
    {
    }

    public SearchBarExHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper commandMapper) : base(mapper ?? SearchBarMapper)
    {
    }

    public override void UpdateValue(string propertyName)
    {
        base.UpdateValue(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == SearchBarLang.CancelButtonTextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (VirtualView is SearchBarLang searchBarLang)
            {
                SetCancelButtonText(searchBarLang.CancelButtonText);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void MapCancelText(SearchBarHandler handler, ISearchBar bar)
    {
        if (handler is SearchBarExHandler searchBarHandler && searchBarHandler.VirtualView is SearchBarLang searchBarLang)
        {
            searchBarHandler.SetCancelButtonText(searchBarLang.CancelButtonText);
        }
    }
}
```

In the platform specific file for IOS you add the magic.

```cs
public partial class SearchBarExHandler : SearchBarHandler
{
    public void SetCancelButtonText(string newCancelButtonText)
    {
        PlatformView.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(newCancelButtonText), new NSString("cancelButtonText"));

        // Now we need to activate the button so it refreshes and take our changes.
        // If the searchbar is empty, this happens automatic when you start to type. 
        if (PlatformView is UISearchBar uiSearchBar)
        {
            bool hasText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uiSearchBar.Text);

            uiSearchBar.ShowsCancelButton = false;
            if (hasText)
            {
                uiSearchBar.ShowsCancelButton = true;
            }

            if (uiSearchBar.ValueForKey(new NSString("cancelButton")) is UIButton cancelButton)
            {
                cancelButton.Enabled = hasText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add your new control to your veiw.

[image]

If you want complete code, check out my [Repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples/tree/main/src/CustomizeHandlers/Handlers/SearchBar)

Comment: Where did you get the information about NSString(„..,“) from? I mean which string to use here etc.? Is there  detailed documentation about that whole? I must admit, I would not have been able to solve this without your help :(

Comment: Also a follow up question: I use a Localization Resource Manager to translate my entire UI with help of resource files and am able to switch Language inside the App. When do you think is the best time to set the language here? When the corresponding views with the SearchBar appear or can this also be done in the SearchHandler and is updated then automatically later when language is switched in the App?

Comment: Reason I was asking first comment question was that I need to translate the „Done“-Button here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451494/ios-keyboard-close-button-missing

Comment: Regarding where to find this information, you need to look for IOS Swift code and learn how to adapt it to C# and .Net MAUI. It is not always possible to convert but with experience you most time get it to work. In this case it was a StackOverflow post that lead me to the right way.

Comment: Regarding the Localization, why dont you set it as a property? Derive Searchbar and make your own property for it. If you not alrady downloaded the source code for MAUI, do that, and learn how they do things. It is a great way to learn how to go about things.

Comment: Regarding the Done-button. Does it not already adapt to Localization? UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done is part of the IOS System so it should do that.

Comment: Currently, it doesn’t. I change the localization internally and it appears to me it is only changing if the OS localization is changed. Also for the Cancel-Button. I think it also changes by default when adding the two languages to the Info.plist. But that’s also only done if the OS localization changes

Comment: How do you change the culture info? [Perhaps this answer can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803673/using-localization-in-net-maui-picker/76809968#76809968)

Comment: This was the configuration in Info.plist which works but not when switching languages internally and keeping the Localization of the OS the same: ```<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>nl</string>
</array>```

Comment: My CultureInfo is set/changed via an static instance of an ```ILocalizationResourceManager```. There, it has a method ```public void SetCulture(CultureInfo newCulture)``` which sets the new culture via ```AppResource.Culture = newCulture``` and then calling ```PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));```

Comment: I updated my question above with how I realized it currently. When I change the localization within the App, I send a LocalizationChangedMessage. In the SearchBarHandler, I receive it and use your way using platformView.SetValueForKey(...). What is not working as wanted right now is that the Text is changed directly after it. Assume you are currently typing Text to a SearchBar and the Cancel-Button-Text is in "en" and still displayed. You navigate to a Flyout-Page with the Settings. After changing language there and re-setting the Cancel-Button-Text it still shows the old one until edit ends

Comment: One thing is that you forgot about your base class. The Ctor should be
`public SearchBarHandler() : base(mapper)` and `public SearchBarHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper commandMapper) : base(mapper)`.

Comment: When initializing my SearchBarHandler as done in MauiProgram.cs breakpoints are only hit in the Standard-Constructor (I implemented all 3 of them). So, actually the code ```public SearchBarHandler() : base(mapper)``` can't be used with a ```base(mapper)```. The constructors with the other parameters are never reached. Maybe I am missing something like an invalidate-routine or update-routine for the UI in case my Language has changed? The Cancel-Button is updated but not while typing something in the Searchbar. I have to unfocus then focus the SearchBar again and it shows the changed Language

Comment: Also maybe I got you wrong and I should use ```SearchBarHandler() : base(Mapper)``` with a capital letter "M". This is possible, but still the Update does not work while typing something in the SearchBar. Still have to delete the text and type again then it is showing the changed language Cancel-Button

Comment: Did you check out how I made my searchbar control to change the search bar icon color? I think you could use this with a property for CancelButtonText. That way you dont need to use weakreferences

Comment: The reason why I was using WeakReferences was that I don’t know how to connect my SettingsViewModel (in which the current language is stored in a property property) could be connected with where I have the property the SearBarHandler is connected to. I think you also register your Handler in MauiProgram.cs, right? The change of the language property could be followed by a NotifyPropertyChange. But how do I connect the Property in SearchBarHandler so that it gets notified about that change. They are in two different classes. So I used the weakreference to notify about that change.

Comment: I have updated the answer, and also my repo so you can find full code there for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great research and your support on this! It helped a lot. Now, I really don't need the WeakReference anymore. Yesterday, I thought I could leave it with my solution which had the charm that I did not need an own control for this and the mapper was applied to every SearchBar I had in my App. Now, I went for the custom Control as you proposed and added it with a property CancelButtonText ```<controls:SearchBarLang Placeholder="{loc:Translate SearchPlaceholder}" CancelButtonText="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" .../>``` which works great now when lang is switched

Comment: It is always nice if you update your question with your finds and upvote good suggestions and if possible mark this as right answer, if you think it helped. That way others can more easily find this.

Comment: Sure, I just marked it as answer. Just for interest - how did you generate the animated image (GIF if it was)?

Comment: It is a program called ScreenToGif.

Comment: Thanks that will certainly help me later on an other place